# Where is best place to house javascript code that monitors a web page and calls off to a web service when some numbers change?

Tags: javascript, plugins

I used to use Excel VBA to launch Internet Explorer and navigate to a url.  That don't work for me no more (perhaps Windows 8).  Anyway, time to take a new approach.  If I want some javscript code to monitor a page like Google Finance and call a web service every time a number changes (like a stock price) where is the best place to house this code?   Should I target a particular browser and write a "plug-in".  I'm having difficulty conceptualising where the code should/can reside.

Comment: you need to save the javascript in some place? I don't understand you completely.

Comment: well, here's a number of scenarios.  1) I have a html webpage with some javascript that monitors the contents of the adjacent tab (is this even possible?) 2) I write some sort of browser extension or plugin that intercepts Http requests.  3) I have a html webpage that acts as a container with some sort of frame set and it monitors the target page like it was a child element.     *** In each case I have to house the html/javascript somewhere I simply have no experience of working in this paradigm; usually I can write a DLL or an EXE and deploy, everything is easier that way.

Comment: OK. In each scenario you need to host the files somewhere (maybe locally when you are in develop environment), but if you need to publish your work you need to save in the cloud your files (like hosting or PaaS services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using JavaScript you should use `setInterval()` to make continuous AJAX requests to the Server. JavaScript is housed in you Browser without a plug-in, but you will need to keep it opened.

Comment: Hang on,  I don't own the page.  Do I "inject" my javascript into their page ? - this doesn't seem fair.  Are HTTP Observers a possible solution?   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads

Comment: Do they have an RSS feed?

Comment: Almost defeinitely not.

Comment: http://www.nasdaq.com/aspxcontent/NasdaqRSS.aspx?data=quotes&symbol=GOOG,MSFT gets the Google and Microsoft rss feeds from NASDAQ directly. You could use PHP's `DOMDocument`, running a loop on the tables. Use `DOMDocument`'s `load` method to load XML. Make sure to suppress errors with `@`.

Comment: I did some PHP 10 years ago.  Anyway, I agree it will be code (Javascript or PHP) using the DOM to inspect the contents of nodes somehow.  Your solution looks like the code will make a periodic request after each interval, this could work.  I'd prefer to work with an OnChange event handler, where would this reside?

Comment: By the way, I think the right answer is Mutation Observers.  But I still need to know where the code is housed.  So could I use a Mutation Observer in script on one tab to observe a mutation on a different tab?